# Does Apache Flink checkpointing need to use with stateful functions?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Does the Apache Flink checkpointing feature need to be used with stateful functions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. If your functions do not have State, nothing will be checkpointed. But be aware that certain built-in functions have state on their own e.g. `FlinkKafkaConsumer`.

Comment: but if i have a flow of.... something.map,flatmap.map... does it means that all what i've already calculated is disposed? or also saved at checkpoint?

Comment: If it was not stored in some `Sink`, then yes those calculations will be disposed and stream will be replayed from last element that went through whole your DAG.